# Garbage collection and closures on local variables

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection, closures

Will xmlHttp get garbage collected and if so, when ?

```
function foo (param)
{
    var xmlHttp = GetXmlHttpRequestObject();

    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200)
        {
            // do something involving param and xmlHttp.responseXML
        }
    }

    xmlHttp.open("GET", "GetAsyncData.ashx", true);
    xmlHttp.send();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the garbage collector will destroy automatically a variable as soon as the function `foo` has been executed (since the variable is local and thus it cannot be used outside the given scope).

This is also one of the reasons why is a good practice to especially use local variables declared with `var` keyword.

Please note that in your specific context, since you perform an asynchronous ajax call, your function is returning while the ajax call is still running so the garbage collector will destroy your `xmlHttp` variable when the both the function is returned and the call has been completed

Comment: Not exactly. If the request is asynchronous, it may hold a closure to the function's execution context that stops it from being garbage collected even though other code execution continues.

Comment: so will it be garbage collected some time after onreadystatechange is called ?